# Process.Start working directory in the same string as filepath

Tags: c#, process

Is there any way to specify working directory as below?

```
Process.Start("c:\someDir\someExecutable.exe + working directory path");
```

or how to make windows environment variable path work with :

```
Process.Start("c:\someDir\someExecutable.exe");
```

I know that *ProcessStartInfo* can be use to specify working directory.
I have my own reason to for wanting to put working directory and file path in same parameter of `Process.Start()`.

Comment: That depends, does some executable allow to provide its working directory as a command line argument? Why can't you use the `ProcessStartInfo`?

Comment: What could be that reason? You must split it at the time of the call ultimately, but it's way better to simply keep both separated all the time or compute one from the other.

Comment: @Sayse because I have to pass file path in to a config file of an application.plus I cannot change the code of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `public static Process Start(string fileName)` is found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx

As you can see the description for that parameter is:

> The name of a document or application file to run in the process.

The remarks also note:

> This overload does not allow command-line arguments for the process. If you need to specify one or more command-line arguments for the process, use the Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) or Process.Start(String, String) overloads.

So in summary no, you can't do this. Even if your program accepted a working directory as a command line argument this overload will not work.